# Ubuntu 14.04 does not update

Tags: software-installation, update-manager

I use `apt get update` and my Ubuntu update starts on:

```
0% [Conectando em br.archive.ubuntu.com (2801:82:80ff:8000::5)] [Conectando em
```

And stays there for a good time. And stays at:

```
0% [Conectando em br.archive.ubuntu.com (2801:82:80ff:8000::5)] [Conectando em
```

And does not update. Do you think there are problems in Canonical's server?

I have just installed Ubuntu. My Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i know.

Please open System -> Updates and change the server for updates.

Sometimes  ipv6 server makes trouble.

roema

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help, however, the link is in Portuguese.

https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/O-que-fazer-apos-instalar-o-Ubuntu-1404